# Allow the use of @GeneratedValue even if column is not primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity, sequence

I have an entity class **SupplierOrder.java** which contains two fields: **cuId** and **orderId**

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "cuId" })
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier_order")
public class SupplierOrder
{
        @Column(name = "cuid", nullable = false)
        private Long cuId;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "supOrd")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "supOrd", sequenceName = "supplier_order_seq", allocationSize = 1 )
        @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
        private Integer orderId;
}
```

When I save my entity the following operation on the database used to undertake

```
1. select next value for supplier_order_seq
2. insert into supplier_order(cuid,order_id)values(101,"<value from the point 1>")
```

Now, I have to flip the primary key. In other words, cuid becomes my new primary key and the rest remains the same.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "orderId" })
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier_order")
public class SupplierOrder
{
        @Id                  //changed primary key from orderId to cuid
        @Column(name = "cuid", nullable = false)
        private Long cuId;
    
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "supOrd")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "supOrd", sequenceName = "supplier_order_seq", allocationSize = 1 )
        @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
        private Integer orderId;
}
```

Now, when I am trying to save my entity the following operations happen:

```
1. insert into supplier_order(cuid,order_id)values(101,NULL)
```

Note: getting next value from the seq **supplier_order_seq** does not happen and because of this, it is giving me error as I cannot save order_id as null. How do I make sure that order_id value should be provided by seq ***supplier_order_seq*** even after changing the primary key?

I have tried referring multiple solutions from the link below but none of them worked.

- https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/113

Answer (score 0):

2023, not sure if it's late to answer in case it's needed for anyone,below solution works without extra table entity for generating ids
assuming you have a generator in db, then you can do below

```
      @GeneratedValue(generator = "table_id_seq_gen")
        @GenericGenerator(
                name = "table_id_seq_gen",
                strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
                parameters = {
                        @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM, value = "table_id_seq"),
                        @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "10"),
// other params if needed
                })
        @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT) // here is the trick
        private Long id;
```

then if you have serial number bigSerial or sth you can do

```
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Long id;
```

the key is @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT), so to summarize

- if by defautl not specified with @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT) ,
  Hibernate only generates for PK as default.
- if specified it would
  work with any column that needs a runtime insert.
  @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)